# Retain scroll position angular when navigating to and from list view

Tags: angular

I have a page with a list of items on a page. When I click on an item I navigate to a page displaying the details of that item. When I navigate back to the list of items page from the item page I would like to return to the scroll position from where I clicked on the item.

Is there a recommended way of achieving this in Angular 5?

Comment: Just to be clear the component you want to preserve the scroll for is completely destroyed so that you need to save the state in a service?  Also is it the page scroll that you're concerned about or a scroll position within the component?

Comment: Yes, the list component is destroyed when I navigate to the item page. I do save some optional params such as search query, page number etc. so I at least return to the correct data.

Comment: It's the page scroll position.